# libpng function calls are all unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, c, dll, linker, libpng

I am trying to link my project against the libpng version 1.6.23 dll library, but my linker only sees all function calls that I make to it as unresolved external symbols. I am using Visual Studio Express 2013. Here is a snippet of the linker's output.

```
1>PNGUtils.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_set_sig_bytes referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl PNGUtils::Read(char const *,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,int &)" (?Read@PNGUtils@@SAPEAXPEBDAEAI1AEAH@Z)
1>PNGUtils.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_sig_cmp referenced in function "private: static bool __cdecl PNGUtils::Validate(struct _iobuf *)" (?Validate@PNGUtils@@CA_NPEAU_iobuf@@@Z)
1>PNGUtils.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_create_read_struct referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl PNGUtils::Read(char const *,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,int &)" (?Read@PNGUtils@@SAPEAXPEBDAEAI1AEAH@Z)
1>PNGUtils.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_set_longjmp_fn referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl PNGUtils::Read(char const *,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,int &)" (?Read@PNGUtils@@SAPEAXPEBDAEAI1AEAH@Z)
1>PNGUtils.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_create_info_struct referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl PNGUtils::Read(char const *,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,int &)" (?Read@PNGUtils@@SAPEAXPEBDAEAI1AEAH@Z)
1>PNGUtils.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_read_info referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl PNGUtils::Read(char const *,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,int &)" (?Read@PNGUtils@@SAPEAXPEBDAEAI1AEAH@Z)
1>PNGUtils.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8 referenced in function "public: static void * __cdecl PNGUtils::Read(char const *,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,int &)" (?Read@PNGUtils@@SAPEAXPEBDAEAI1AEAH@Z)
```

I am linking successfully with other libraries such as lua and glew, and I am to my knowledge doing nothing different when trying to link to libpng.

Strangely, when I put the linker into verbose mode. It states...

```
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>  
1>  Unused libraries:
1>    libs\png\libpng16.lib
```

The linker seems to claim that I am not using the libpng library even though I am clearly calling its functions such as in my code segment here in PNGUtils.cpp Read method.

```
png_structp pngPtr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (!pngPtr)
{
    LOG(LOG_CHANNEL_ERROR, "PNGUtils: Couldn't initialize png read struct");

    fclose(fp);

    return NULL;
}

png_infop infoPtr = png_create_info_struct(pngPtr);
if (!infoPtr) 
{
    LOG(LOG_CHANNEL_ERROR, "PNGUtils: Couldn't initialize png info struct");
    png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, (png_infopp)0, (png_infopp)0);

    fclose(fp);

    return NULL;
}
```

I feel lost on why the linker seems to be ignoring the function calls to libpng. I would be happy to hear any thoughts or answers and am of course more than willing to provide any more information on request.

Comment: I think the 'Unused libraries' part means that the linker is ignoring that library when creating the object files / executable. You must find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that your project and your libpng.dll were built with
the same settings, as explained in the projects/vstudio/README.txt that comes with libpng:

> WARNING
>   ======= Libpng 1.6.x does not use the default run-time library when
>   building static library builds of libpng; instead of the shared DLL
>   runtime it uses a static runtime.  If you need to change this make
>   sure to change the setting on all the relevant projects:
>
> ```
> libpng
> zlib
> all the test programs
> ```
>
> The runtime library settings for each build are as follows:
>
> ```
>            Release        Debug
> DLL         /MD            /MDd
> Library     /MT            /MTd
> ```
>
> NOTICE that libpng 1.5.x erroneously used /MD for Debug DLL builds; if
>   you used the debug builds in your app and you changed your app to use
>   /MD you will need to change it back to /MDd for libpng 1.6.0 and
>   later.
>
> The Visual Studio 2010 defaults for a Win32 DLL or Static Library
>   project are as follows:
>
> ```
>                  Release     Debug
> DLL               /MD         /MDd
> Static Library    /MD         /MDd
> ```
>
> Also, be sure to build libpng, zlib, and your project all for the same
>   platform (e.g., 32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: I am sure that was a step in the right direction, thanks for pointing that out. I finally fixed it by compiling the libpng source code to be 64bit since my project is 64bit. The errors are now gone.

Comment: I'll add that (about 32bit vs 64bit) to the libpng doc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a newbie question here. How to change the runtime library setting in visual studio? I could not change in debugging, DLL ---> /MDd, and Library --> MTd as you suggest.  So far only find *Runtime Library" in "Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Code Generation "

Answer (score 0):

cI know the question is a bit old, but maybe there are people having same difficulties.

In my case 2 steps to solve "unresolved link" (with Visual Studio 16.4.6 2019) issue were:

- to compile my project as x86 (as the libraries I was using were built under this architecture) and use 32 bits version of libpng .dll
- add zlib (including zlib.h in the code and linking with the corresponding .dll and .lib)

After doing this, it compiled sucessfully.